# sqlite - How to get INSERT OR IGNORE to work

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to insert data into a table. I would like to insert the row if the column doesn't have the data already - regardless of the other columns.

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name        VARCHAR,
    other       INT
);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO t (name) VALUES ('a');
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO t (name) VALUES ('a');
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO t (name) VALUES ('a');
```

With the above snippet I end up with 3 rows, not 1 as I would have thought. If it matters the actual sql is happening inside of a `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger, this is just a simple test case.

Comment: Please note [that](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html): `INSERT OR IGNORE` is the exact equivalent to: `INSERT ON CONFLICT IGNORE`.

Comment: nothing to ignore, since name is not unique

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Replace

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name        VARCHAR,
    other       INT
);
```

with

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name        VARCHAR UNIQUE,
    other       INT
);
```

Then you will get

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE t (
   ...>     id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   ...>     name        VARCHAR UNIQUE,
   ...>     other       INT
   ...> );
sqlite> INSERT OR IGNORE INTO t (name) VALUES ('a');
sqlite> INSERT OR IGNORE INTO t (name) VALUES ('a');
sqlite> INSERT OR IGNORE INTO t (name) VALUES ('a');
sqlite> select * from t ;
1|a|
```

Answer (score 33):

That would only work for the primary key field or unique constraints:

> The optional conflict-clause allows the specification of an
>   alternative constraint conflict resolution algorithm to use during
>   this one [INSERT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) command.

Further:

> The [ON CONFLICT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) clause applies to UNIQUE and NOT NULL constraints
>   (and to PRIMARY KEY constraints which for the purposes of this section
>   are the same thing as UNIQUE constraints). The ON CONFLICT algorithm
>   does not apply to FOREIGN KEY constraints. There are five conflict
>   resolution algorithm choices: ROLLBACK, ABORT, FAIL, IGNORE, and
>   REPLACE. The default conflict resolution algorithm is ABORT.

Comment: can you provide code? Mine doesn't work still