# Raw Query in Android SQLite - INSERT OR IGNORE

Tags: java, android, sqlite, insert

I'm having an issue inputting information into a Sqlite database on the app I'm creating.  I was using the help of the Cursor before.  I am used to MySQL although clearly not 'used to' that well.

I am trying to add to the database from a file.  I had this working before but it would be added with the Cursor. I was then told that in order to make it so I could add new information to the file and have the app ONLY add the new information into the database I should use INSERT OR IGNORE.

Is this the correct syntax?  I currently am not having any information inserted for whatever reason...

```
ourDatabase.rawQuery("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("+KEY_CLASS+",
 " + KEY_QUESTION+ ") VALUES ('" + qclass + "', '" + question + "');", null);
```

This is my database:

```
"CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + 
                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                    KEY_CLASS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_QUESTION + " TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE);
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: remove the semi-colon in your query "');"

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately that did not work though. I posted my database just to ensure I'm doing things properly.. Thanks!

Comment: Look : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105198/sqlite-how-to-get-insert-or-ignore-to-work)

Comment: This is what I was basing my query off of Markus, however it still wasn't working. Thanks for the link though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query seems right but try the one below anyway

```
ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();
insertValues.put(KEY_CLASS, qclass);
insertValues.put(KEY_QUESTION, question);   
yourDbName.insertWithOnConflict(DATABASE_TABLE, null, insertValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);  

KEY_QUESTION + " TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE);";
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That works perfectly!  I didn't know there was a way to do the Conflict ignore thing with ContentValues.  Appreciate it! (I would up-vote but I don't have enough rep...)

Comment: You should try not to use rawQuery unless you have to, the other query method seems more typing but it can save you a lot of headache. Always use the selectionArgs.

Comment: Theoretically how would you do this with raw query?

Comment: "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("+KEY_CLASS+",
 " + KEY_QUESTION+ ") VALUES (?, ?)", new String[]{qclass, question};