# how to not insert common data in a column in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table named `category` and the table looks like

```
cat_id    cat_name
1          Science
2          Arts
```

and another table named `item` which looks like

```
item_id  item_name  cat_id
1          physics    1
2          literature 2
3          chemistry  1
```

please mark that `cat_id` is the foreign key here of `item` table.

now I want that If I put `math` as `item_name` under `Arts` category then it will insert successfully but I want this to happen in such a way that if I want to put same data again then it wont insert. please mark also that I have cat_name and item_name only then my query fetches the category_id using `cat_name` from category table and inserts into the item table like this way

```
insert into item (item_name,cat_id) select 'math',category.cat_id from category where category.cat_name = 'Arts'
```

but if I run this query again it inserts the same item `math` again, but I want to stop this to happen, what should I do?

Comment: You could either check the database before inserting or set the column `item_name` as unique in MySQL, it'll throw an error.

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQLite?

Comment: SQLITE database is preferable

Comment: Updated my query, please re-check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reyjohn, can't you define the column as unique? That will prevent duplicate values.

I don't use sqlite but my impression is it uses similar syntax to MySQL, but without some of the stricter checks.

As per this answer:
[sqlite - How to get INSERT OR IGNORE to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105198/sqlite-how-to-get-insert-or-ignore-to-work)

You could use `INSERT OR IGNORE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite doesn't have "INSERT OR UPDATE" which would be perfect for your case.

But you can emulate it with "INSERT OR REPLACE" - which is supported by SQLite - together with a "UNION". I developed this technique because I wanted to issue one single query and let the SQLite engine do everything.

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO item (item_id, item_name, cat_id)
    SELECT item_id, item_name, cat_id FROM (

       SELECT item_id, item_name, 'new_category' FROM item
       WHERE item_name='math'

       UNION

       SELECT NULL, 'math', 'new_category'

    ) ORDER BY item_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

So you are basically making one "SELECT WHERE item_name='math'" to get the existing record (if it exists) and then you concatenate this result (UNION) with a SELECT that generates a new record with a NULL item_id.

The trick then is the "ORDER BY item_id DESC LIMIT 1" at the end, where the actual result for the INSERT statement is exactly 1 record: the one that existed, with same item_id and a 'new_category' or a new one with a NULL item_id, which forces SQLite to create one for you.

You can also check if record exists before (with a SELECT) and decide if you need an INSERT or an UPDATE. But this leads to 2 queries and additional code on the client side. Thats why I developed the technique above.