# Check if certain values in a database table already exist

Tags: sqlite, delphi, delphi-xe4

I would like to check if two values ('shift' and 'date') already exist in another table called "LOG" before I post data to it. The 'shift' value is determined by a selection in the grid that displays data from the "shifts" table (UNITable1) and date parameter is  the AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text (it displays current date). The query is this:

```
 procedure TForm1.cxButton4Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
    UniTransaction1.AddConnection(UniConnection1);
    UNIquery2.Close;
    UNIquery2.SQL.Clear;
    UNIquery2.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO LOG (DATE,SHIFT,TASK,DONE) VALUES (:a1,:a2,:a3,:a4)');
    UNIquery2.Prepare;
    UniTransaction1.StartTransaction;
    try
    UNIQuery1.DisableControls;
    UNIQuery1.First;
    while Uniquery1.EOF = false do begin
    UNIquery2.Params[0].asString := AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text; //Current Date
    UNIquery2.Params[1].asString := UniTable1.FieldByName('SHIFT').asString;// Which shift
    UNIquery2.Params[2].asString := Uniquery1.FieldByName('TASK').asString;//many tasks
    UNIquery2.Params[3].Value := Uniquery1.FieldByName('DONE').Value;// Checkbox
    Uniquery1.Next; //get 'all' the values from UNIQuery1
    UNIquery2.ExecSQL;
    end;
    UniTransaction1.Commit;
    UNIQuery1.EnableControls;
    finally
    if UNIquery2.Connection.InTransaction then
    UNIquery2.Connection.Rollback;
    end;
    end;
```

How can I incorporate this ? How can I rewrite this transaction so it checks for the existing records ???

Edited: UNIQuery1 is iterating through other records that I want inserted.

Comment: If you properly indented your code formatting, it would be much easier to understand.

Comment: If you can't decide where the else should go, you're clearly not comprehending how your own code is supposed to work.  Anyway, if the Sql assigned to UNIQuery2 correctly selects existing record(s) for the shift, then UNIQuery2.EOF will be false immediately after you call Open on it.  You should be able to figure it out from there.  Key points:  1) Follow Jerry Dodge's advice and 2) stop using the "With" construct - it will get you into all sorts of trouble.

Comment: I'm not sure you need the QuotedString(); you may have to check.

Comment: IS it correct that Prepare is called BEFORE making a connection attached to the dataset ?

Comment: @MartynA - if I am not mistaken the query must iterate through all records till the last records. If it finds no adequate records I close it and contunue with new SQL.

Comment: if you just want to avoid dublicates you can use a unique key and an insert or ignore statement http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105198/sqlite-how-to-get-insert-or-ignore-to-work

Comment: That would only work for the primary key field or unique constraints.

Comment: your description hints at the fact that 'shift' and 'date' should be unique, why not create such a constraint?

Comment: @ fuchs777 - cant do that in a LOG table since all inserts go there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use whatever components you're referring to (I have no idea what a `UNIQuery2` or `UNITransaction` might be, but your logic is totally out of whack. (So is your formatting, which is simply atrocious - if that's how your real code works, you really need to learn better habits.)

And please - get rid of the use of `with` now. It's highly prone to error, makes code hard to read and comprehend, and makes debugging extremely difficult.

You need to (in this order):

- Connect to the database
- Set up your query
- Prepare your query
- Set your parameters
- Start your transaction
- Begin a try (finally)
- Begin a try (except)
- Execute your query
- On exception, roll back your query
- If no exception, commit your transaction
- In finally, close the query and connection

Also, if your components are compatible with `TDataSet`, it should support `TDataSet.IsEmpty` that you should use (`if not UNIQuery2.IsEmpty then`) instead of `if UNIQuery.Eof = false` (which should more cleanly be `if not UNIQuery.Eof`).

I can't make an effort to re-work your code, because it's all over the place. You have `UNIQuery2` in one place, `UNIQuery1` in another (and the `with` statement that makes it all more confusing), and I don't use (or have) whatever components you're using to even try to figure it out. I hope this information can help you sort it out. If not, post a new question with your cleaned up (rewritten) code, more clear information about the problems you're having, and try to ask a clearer question, and we can be more help.

Comment: UNI (table/query/transaction) are a part of the UNIDAC components from Devart. The queries are all where they should be. I have no issue with the execution of any of the queries. I have cleared a code a little bit so I hope you understand me.