# Number of rows affected after insert or ignore into

Tags: perl, sqlite, dbi

The `perl` code gives me number of rows affected as 1 even though the record gets ignored by the sql statement because of `PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT` while inserting into a sqlite database using DBI module.

```
my $stmt = 'INSERT OR IGNORE INTO table1 (ID, Name) VALUES (?,?)';
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($stmt);

$sth->bind_param( 1, $id, SQL_VARCHAR );
$sth->bind_param( 2, $name, SQL_VARCHAR );

my $row =  $sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
print "Row affected for id[$id]- $row\n";
```

It always gives me $row as 1 for below set of data where `ID & NAME` are composite primary key-

```
ID   NAME
1    AAA
1    BBB
1    AAA
2    BBB
2    BBB
```

anything wrong I am doing here. I need to execute another section of code based on value 0f $row that is 0 in case of IGNORE and 1 in case of INSERTION.

Is there any other way to handle it?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105198/sqlite-how-to-get-insert-or-ignore-to-work

Comment: I'll second @mob's recommendation.  Seem silly, but you'll have to use a 2nd (temp) table to store the results from your `INSERT OR IGNORE`.  You can then `select *` on the 2nd table, and then you should be able to count the rows affected by the `INSERT OR IGNORE`.

Comment: I don't know about Perl, but everywhere else I've tried, SQLite counts the changes correctly. Show the table definition.

Comment: @CL you are right. This is more related to Perl and sql query work well with the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.016;
use DBI;

my $h = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:db=x.db");
eval {
    $h->do(q/drop table test/);
};

$h->do(q/create table test (id integer, name varchar(10), constraint xx unique(id,name))/);

my $s = $h->prepare(q/insert or ignore into test values(?,?)/);
my @values = ([1, 'AAA'], [1, 'BBB'], [1, 'AAA'], [2, 'BBB'], [2, 'BBB']);
foreach (@values) {
    my $affected = $s->execute(@{$_});
    say join(",", @{$_}) . " = $affected";
}
$h->disconnect;
```

outputs

```
1,AAA = 1
1,BBB = 1
1,AAA = 0E0
2,BBB = 1
2,BBB = 0E0
```

for me which looks correct. I am using DBI 1.631 and DBD::SQLite 1.42.

Comment: Thanks bohica. This code also worked for me. I am not sure if I did any mess with error handling. I think I need to check back my code again.