# how i can check if DB have data and insert new rows in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on android app to save data from json in to sqlite database ,
data is save but if user loging again The same data will be insert again In the new rows in the database

What shoud i do to stop insert same data for every login
, if have new data save it only

i try to add this code in addCustomer but it save only one row

```
Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM " + BookingTabel.TABLE_CUSTOMER, null);
if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst() && cur.getInt(0) > 0) {

    Log.i(getClass().getName(), "table not empty");
} 
else {

    Log.i(getClass().getName(), "table is empty");
    customer_id = db.insert(TABLE_CUSTOMER, null, values);
}
```

this is my SqlitleHelper

```
public class BookingTabel extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DB_NAME = "MyDB";

    // Bookinks table name

   private static final String TABLE_BOOKINDS = "bookings";
   private static final String TABLE_CUSTOMER = "customer";
   private static final String TABLE_SERVICE = "service";
   private static final String TABLE_SERVICE_ATTRIBUTE = "service_attribute";
   private static final String TABLE_SERVICE_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE = "service_attribute_value";
   private static final String TABLE_INVOICE = "invoice";
   private static final String TABLE_ESTIMATE = "estimate";

   // Bookings Table Columns names
   private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
   private static final String KEY_BOOKING_ID = "booking_id";
   private static final String KEY_BOOKING_NUM = "booking_num";
   private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
   private static final String KEY_BOOKING_START= "booking_start";
   private static final String KEY_BOOKING_END = "booking_end";
   private static final String KEY_PROPERTY = "property_type";
   private static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
   private static final String KEY_ACCEPT_STATUS = "accept_status";
   private static final String KEY_BOOKING_ADDRESS = "booking_address";
   private static final String KEY_PO_BOX = "po_box";
   private static final String KEY_CREATED = "created";
   private static final String KEY_POSTCODE = "postcode";
   private static final String KEY_STATE = "state";
   private static final String KEY_STREET_ADDRESS = "street_address";
   private static final String KEY_STREET_NUMBER = "street_number";
   private static final String KEY_SUBURB = "suburb";
   private static final String KEY_UNIT_LOT_NUMBER = "unit_lot_number";
   private static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";
   private static final String KEY_CONVERT_STATUS = "convert_status";
   private static final String KEY_QOUTE = "qoute";
   private static final String KEY_SUB_TOTAL = "sub_total";
   private static final String KEY_TOTAL_DISCOUNT = "total_discount";
   private static final String KEY_BOOKING_DISTANCE = "booking_distance";
   private static final String KEY_GST = "gst";
   private static final String KEY_ORIGINAL_BOOKING_ID = "original_booking_id";

   //*************** Customer Table Columns names *****************//
   private static final String KEY_CUSTOMER_ID = "customer_id";
   private static final String KEY_CUSTOMER_NAME = "name";
   private static final String KEY_CUSTOMER_EMAIL1 = "email1";
   private static final String KEY_CUSTOMER_EMAIL2 = "email2";
   private static final String KEY_CUSTOMER_EMAIL3 = "email3";
   private static final String KEY_CUSTOMER_MOBILE1 = "mobile1";
   private static final String KEY_CUSTOMER_MOBILE2 = "mobile2";
   private static final String KEY_CUSTOMER_MOBILE3 = "mobile3";
   private static final String KEY_CUSTOMER_PHONE1 = "phone1";
   private static final String KEY_CUSTOMER_PHONE2 = "phone2";
   private static final String KEY_CUSTOMER_PHONE3 = "phone3";
   private static final String KEY_CUSTOMER_CITY = "city";
   private static final String KEY_CUSTOMER_COUNTRY = "country";
   private static final String KEY_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS = "address";
   private static final String KEY_CUSTOMER_FAX = "fax";
   private static final String KEY_CUSTOMER_ORIGINAL_CUSTOMER_ID = "original_customer_id";


   public BookingTabel(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null,DB_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    private static final String[] COLUMNS = {KEY_ID,KEY_BOOKING_NUM,KEY_TITLE,KEY_BOOKING_START,KEY_BOOKING_END,KEY_PROPERTY, KEY_CUSTOMER_ID,KEY_DESCRIPTION,KEY_ACCEPT_STATUS,KEY_BOOKING_ADDRESS,KEY_PO_BOX,KEY_CREATED , KEY_POSTCODE,KEY_STATE,KEY_STREET_ADDRESS,KEY_STREET_NUMBER,KEY_SUBURB,KEY_UNIT_LOT_NUMBER,KEY_STATUS, KEY_CONVERT_STATUS,KEY_QOUTE,KEY_SUB_TOTAL,KEY_TOTAL_DISCOUNT,KEY_BOOKING_DISTANCE,KEY_GST, KEY_ORIGINAL_BOOKING_ID};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // SQL statement to create book table
        String CREATE_BOOKINDS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE bookings ( " + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,"+ "booking_num VARCHAR(250) ,"+ "title VARCHAR(250) ," + "booking_start DATETIME ,"+"booking_end DATETIME ,"+"property_type VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'House'," + "customer_id LONG ,"+"description TEXT ,"+"accept_status VARCHAR(250) ,"+"booking_address VARCHAR(250), " + "po_box VARCHAR(250) , "+ "created INTEGER ,"+ "postcode INTEGER ,"+"state VARCHAR(250) ," + "street_address VARCHAR(250) ,"+"street_number INTEGER ,"+"suburb VARCHAR(250) ,"+"unit_lot_number INTEGER ," + "status VARCHAR(250) ,"+"convert_status VARCHAR(250) ,"+"qoute FLOAT ,"+"sub_total FLOAT ,"+"total_discount FLOAT ," + "booking_distance FLOAT ,"+"gst FLOAT ,"+"original_booking_id INTEGER )";


        String CREATE_TABLE_CUSTOMER = "CREATE TABLE customer ( "+ "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+ "name VARCHAR(250),"+ "email1 VARCHAR(250)," + "email2 VARCHAR(250) ," + "email3 VARCHAR(250) , " + "mobile1 VARCHAR(250), " + "mobile2 VARCHAR(250), " + "mobile3 VARCHAR(250)," + "phone1 VARCHAR(250)," + "phone2 VARCHAR(250)," + "phone3 VARCHAR(250)," + "city VARCHAR(250)," + "country VARCHAR(250)," + "address VARCHAR(250)," + "fax VARCHAR9(250)," + "original_customer_id INTEGER )";

        // create bookings table

        db.execSQL(CREATE_BOOKINDS_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CUSTOMER);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bookings");
        // create fresh bookings table
        this.onCreate(db);
    }

    public long addCustomer(String name,String email1,String email2, String email3, String mobile1,String mobile2,String mobile3,String phone1,String phone2,String phone3,String city,String country,String address ,String fax,String original_customer_id/*,String original_booking_id*/) {


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_CUSTOMER_NAME,name );
        values.put(KEY_CUSTOMER_EMAIL1 ,email1 );
        values.put(KEY_CUSTOMER_EMAIL2 ,email2 );
        values.put(KEY_CUSTOMER_EMAIL3 ,email3  );
        values.put(KEY_CUSTOMER_MOBILE1 ,mobile1);
        values.put( KEY_CUSTOMER_MOBILE2,mobile2);
        values.put( KEY_CUSTOMER_MOBILE3,mobile3);
        values.put( KEY_CUSTOMER_PHONE1,phone1);
        values.put( KEY_CUSTOMER_PHONE2,phone2 );
        values.put( KEY_CUSTOMER_PHONE3,phone3 );
        values.put( KEY_CUSTOMER_CITY,city);
        values.put( KEY_CUSTOMER_COUNTRY,country );
        values.put( KEY_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS,address );
        values.put( KEY_CUSTOMER_FAX,fax);
        values.put( KEY_CUSTOMER_ORIGINAL_CUSTOMER_ID,original_customer_id);
        //values.put(KEY_ORIGINAL_BOOKING_ID, original_booking_id);

        long customer_id = db.insert(TABLE_CUSTOMER, null, values);
        db.close();

        return  customer_id ;
    }

    //*************** ADD Bookings In Database *****************//

    public long addBookings(String booking_num,String title,String booking_start,String booking_end,String property_type,long customer_id,String description,String accept_status,String booking_address,String po_box,String created ,String postcode,String state,String street_address,String street_number,String suburb,String unit_lot_number,String status,String convert_status,String qoute,String sub_total,String total_discount,String booking_distance,String gst, String original_booking_id) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_BOOKING_NUM,booking_num );
        values.put(KEY_TITLE,title );
        values.put(KEY_BOOKING_START ,booking_start );
        values.put(KEY_BOOKING_END ,booking_end );
        values.put(KEY_PROPERTY ,property_type  );
        values.put(KEY_CUSTOMER_ID, customer_id);
        //  System.out.println("CUSTOMER ID:*****" + customer_id);
        values.put( KEY_DESCRIPTION,description   );
        values.put( KEY_ACCEPT_STATUS,accept_status   );
        values.put( KEY_BOOKING_ADDRESS,booking_address );
        values.put( KEY_PO_BOX,po_box );
        values.put( KEY_CREATED,created  );
        values.put( KEY_POSTCODE,postcode);
        values.put( KEY_STATE,state );
        values.put( KEY_STREET_ADDRESS,street_address );
        values.put( KEY_STREET_NUMBER,street_number);
        values.put( KEY_SUBURB,suburb);
        values.put( KEY_UNIT_LOT_NUMBER,unit_lot_number);
        values.put( KEY_STATUS,status );
        values.put( KEY_CONVERT_STATUS,convert_status);
        values.put( KEY_QOUTE,qoute);
        values.put( KEY_SUB_TOTAL,sub_total );
        values.put( KEY_TOTAL_DISCOUNT,total_discount);
        values.put( KEY_BOOKING_DISTANCE,booking_distance );
        values.put( KEY_GST,gst);
        values.put( KEY_ORIGINAL_BOOKING_ID,original_booking_id );

        long booking_id = db.insert(TABLE_BOOKINDS, null, values);
        db.close();
        return booking_id;
    }
```

Comment: you have to put this in loop

Comment: yes i put it in loop
for (int i = 0; i < resultArr.length(); i++) {
// add customer table
long customer_id =dba.addCustomer(name,email1,email2,email3,mobile1,mobile2,mobile3,
phone1,phone2,phone3 ,city,country,address ,fax,original_customer_id);

Comment: then you have to check it, it's value unique ness.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code will chekc if data exists in database. Now you will have to change the query I used to check any unique value you are storing in your database when user logs in.

```
public static boolean CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot(String TableName,
        String dbfield, String fieldValue) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqldb = EGLifeStyleApplication.sqLiteDatabase;
    String Query = "Select * from " + TableName + " where " + dbfield + "="
            + fieldValue;
    Cursor cursor = sqldb.rawQuery(Query, null);
            if(cursor.getCount<=0){
    return false;
           }
        return true;
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20416004/609782)

Comment: Adding a downvote should accompny with a comment mentioning the reason so that one can improve their answers in future.

Answer (score 0):

consider using `INSERT OR IGNORE` in SQLite:

1. make a unique field in `customer` table, e.g. `name VARCHAR(250) UNIQUE`
2. user `execSQL` method to make `INSERT OR IGNORE` query

refer to [sqlite - How to get INSERT OR IGNORE to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105198/sqlite-how-to-get-insert-or-ignore-to-work/12105319#12105319)